# Prototype: select element containing text (as jQuery :contains())

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Using Prototype I have to select and hide all `<li>` elements containing the word `Foo` inside:

```
<li><label>Lorem Lipsum Foo</label></li>
<li><label>Lorem Lipsum Bar</label></li>
```

I know with jQuery it is as easy as `$('li:contains("Foo")').hide()`, but could not find a way to do that in Prototype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
[].forEach.call(lis, function (li) {
  if (li.textContent.indexOf("Foo") > -1) {
    li.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

Seriously, you don't need libraries for this. Just a good bit of DOM4 & ES5 does it for you.

Use the normal shims if you care about legacy platform support

SideNote: don't ever do `$("li:contains('Foo')")` its epicly slow as hell. Not to mention murderous abuse of selectors4

Comment: Thanks, that works pretty well. I didnt know about `[].forEach` was native javascript. Although what I need is not for production use.

Answer (score 2):

`:contains` does work in Prototype, you just need to remember that the output of [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) is an array.

```
$$('li:contains("Foo")').invoke('hide');
```

Comment: This returned me an array containing all elements in the page =P, including `html`, `head`, `link`, ... are you sure prototype implements the `:contains()` selector?

Comment: Here is [a fiddle demonstrating it](http://jsfiddle.net/kHC48/). By playing with it I find that Prototype 1.6 doesn't work, only version 1.7 does.