# Hide element (li) that contains "some string"?

Tags: css, prototypejs

I want to hide one `<li>` element of many which contains (inner HTML) the string "whatever". Is there way to do that without knowing the exact structure of the innerHTML of the `<li>`s?

I know how to hide it, just the finding is the problem. I can use Prototype to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototype: select element containing text (as jQuery :contains())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081918/prototype-select-element-containing-text-as-jquery-contains)

Comment: See the other question linked above - there may be ways to improve the speed of the CSS selector by limiting the scope to a group of elements - but I would have to see more of your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$$("li:contains('whatever')").invoke("hide");
```

To explain: `$$("li:contains('whatever')")` returns a list of `<li>`s that contain "whatever", and then we `invoke` the `hide` method on everything in that list.

[Here's a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xptwL/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually since 1.7.X prototype.js is by default using exactly the same selector engine as jQuery, Sizzle:

http://sizzlejs.com/

As stated here:

http://prototypejs.org/2010/04/05/prototype-1-7-rc1-sizzle-layout-dimensions-api-event-delegation-and-more/

Thus methods proposed by Evan Hahn should do the trick.