# Javascript invoke hide and store string text as variable within LI tag

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299888/hide-element-li-that-contains-some-string) I was able to hide a list element that contained some string text.  I'd like to re-use everything within these `<LI></LI>` tags however someplace else within the page.  The entire contents of the LI tags can vary but will share the one common element I'm able to invoke the hide with.  Is there some way to adjust this code to store everything found as a variable after I successfully hide it?

```
Event.observe(window, "load", function(){

$$("li:contains('Full Listing Information:')").invoke("hide");
});
```

Comment: `observe` and `invoke` are from Prototype.js, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign it to a variable.

```
var listings;
Event.observe(window, "load", function(){
    listings = $$("li:contains('Full Listing Information:')");
    listings.invoke("hide");
});
```

Comment: Hmmmm...  <?php echo $listings ; ?> didn't display it though?

Comment: This code is Javascript, it runs on the client. PHP runs on the server.

Comment: How would I display that someplace else in the html page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to display. `listings` is a collection of DOM elements, not text.

Comment: I want to store everything within the LI tags as a text variable to output later in the html page.

Comment: I don't really know Prototype, but I assume it has a method like jQuery `.text()` to get the text out of an object. You can then display that in some element.

Comment: Do you know how to display the contents of the LI tags if you're **not** hiding it first? I don't think it should be any different.

Comment: `$$()` returns an array of DOM Elements, so you can do `listings.toString()` but its going to return something like `[<LIElement>,<LIElement>]`

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a `div#output` elsewhere on the page, and you want to put the text of your list items into it, each wrapped in an h2. Let's also imagine that you want to leave the other list items (the ones that don't match your selector) alone where they are. This should do the trick:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
  var listings = $$("li:contains('Full Listing Information:')").invoke('hide').map(function(elm){ return elm.innerText });
  var t = new Template('<h2>#{text}</h2>')
  listings.each(function(str){
    $('output').insert(t.evaluate({text: str}))
  });
});
```

Inside the first line, you first hide each of the matching list items, then extract the text content from them into an array. The last three lines iterate over that array, building a new h2 each turn, and inserting it into your recipient div. The outer wrapper just makes certain that the DOM is stable before you run this. It can run before the rest of the page is visible, so you shouldn't have the Flash Of Unstyled Content to worry about.